# LS regression with order constraint

Tags: r, optimization, regression, least-squares, simplex

I'm new to R and would appreciate your assistance. 
I have an optimization problem with a constraint. Although there are several ways to solve an optimization in R, I could not express my problem correctly with the constraint I need to apply.

Suppose I have the following data in three categories:

```
A<-c(99.1,  96.5,   94.4,   92.7,   91.5,   91.3,   91.4,   90.1,   87.1,   82.6,   76.4)
B<-c(146.4, 140.2,  133.6,  126.5,  118.7,  109.4,  101.2,  101.8,  103.7,  102.5,  98.3)
C<-c(237.5, 213.9,  191,    168.9,  147.4,  124.9,  108.3,  95.7,   84.4,   73.5,   63)
t<-seq(1:11)
DT<-cbind.data.frame(t,A,B,C)
```

I would like to fit an exponential function *y(t)* to data points in each of the categories (minimizing the squared errors), so that *y(t)_c > y(t)_b > y(t)_a >* 0 for selected *t* [1;15]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to incorporate the constraint into regression.
Just construct three separate regressions:

```
fit_loga <- lm(y ~ log(A) + t, data=DT) 
fit_logb <- lm(y ~ log(B) + t, data=DT) 
fit_logc <- lm(y ~ log(C) + t, data=DT)

fit_a <- exp(A)
fit_b <- exp(B)
fit_c <- exp(C)
```

then verify that they satisfy the constraint everywhere on that range (or at least, at every integer datapoint): `(fit_c > fit_b) & (fit_b > fit_a)`. Only if not, then we worry about it. like throw in some other terms in t into the model, perhaps `exp(t)`, `I(t^2)`, `poly(t, <order>)`...

EDIT: I was unaware of `solnp` package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply smci! I was thinking to make it in two steps like you suggest, but how would you do that in this case when C clearly intersects B and A?
I am afraid that i need to keep the same assumption of curve form (here: exponential) for all the curves. Therefore, parameters of one would affect the parameters of another, which requires optimization to be run on them all at once. I completely agree that you should rather look for parameters of linear curves in log space, than trying to fit exponential curves.

Comment: Oh crap. Well if they intersect then how do we apply that constraint? Without doing something kludgy like clamping using min/max?

Comment: I thought that the problem could be solved with an optimization function like {solnp()} that can handle inequality constrains. However, it does not converge or results in infeasible solution when applied directly to minimize squared errors with given constrains

Comment: @Walle: I don't know `solnp`. Suggest you add your code and the infeasible error to the question details and title. Also, that would be more on-topic over at [CrossValidated.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It turned out to be the formatting issues with `solnp()` as the function expected all the parameters to be estimated, as input in one single vector. Therefore I had to transform the matrix I had to a vector and it worked. Not really clear from the error messages that one is getting while running the function, i.e. `non-numeric argument to binary operator` for infeasible constrains (too tight). Not sure if i should post the code or just close this subject.

Comment: @Walle: glad you solved it. Please do post your code and add your own answer. Yes, R error messages are often cryptic and poorly-documented. If you can suggest to the `solnp` authors how to improve that error message and/or documentation, by all means please do (both here and in a docbug or on their list), that's the only way things till get improved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the error messages that one gets using `solnp` mostly refer to inadequate constrains. Also, as it is stated in the documentation, it is required to put all the parameters in one vector. After appropriate adjustments to the code, I was able to implement my constrains of `y(t)_c > y(t)_b > y(t)_a > 0` directly, without any need for altering the problem. The most convenient way is to use matrix formation for the solver. 
Using the data above, I've got the following:
[Results shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHdxp.png)

```
library(data.table)
library(Rsolnp)

t<-as.vector(10:20)
DT<-cbind.data.frame(A,B,C)
tlogDT<-transpose(log(DT))

# min[log(y)'- Ax-b]
# Arr = [A1 A2 .. An b1 b2 .. bn]

gofn = function(arrin)
{
  arr = cbind(arrin[1:3],arrin[4:6])
  sum(
    (as.matrix(arr[,1])%*%t + arr[,2] - tlogDT)^2
  )
}

nocross=t #defines the times where the curves are not allowed to intersect
ineqfn2=function(arrin)
{
  #constrains:
  # 0<f_a(t)<f_b(t)<f_c(t), for some t,
  arr = cbind(arrin[1:3],arrin[4:6])
  nextarr=as.matrix(rbind(rep(0,2),arr[1:(length(arr[,1])-1),]))
  ineqmat=as.matrix(arr[,1])%*%nocross+arr[,2]-nextarr[,1]%*%nocross-nextarr[,2]
  as.vector(t(ineqmat))
}

#lines should be aligned with the first startvalue
eqfn = function(arrin)
{  
  arr = cbind(arrin[1:3],arrin[4:6])
  arr[,1]*t[1]+arr[,2]-tlogDT[,1]
}
#start values:
An=c(1,1,1)
bn=tlogDT[,1]
vstart=c(An,bn)

r <- solnp(
  vstart,  gofn,

  eqfun = eqfn, eqB= c(0,0,0),

  ineqfun = ineqfn2,
  ineqLB = rep(0,length(DT[1,])*length(nocross)),
  ineqUB = rep(5000,length(DT[1,])*length(nocross))
)

r$pars[1]
line1 = exp(r$pars[4]+r$pars[1]*t)
line2 = exp(r$pars[5]+r$pars[2]*t)
line3 = exp(r$pars[6]+r$pars[3]*t)

plot(t, DT[,3],log = "y")
points(t, DT[,2],col="green")
points(t, DT[,1],col="blue")

lines(t, line1,lwd=2, col = "blue",  xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Counts")
lines(t, line2,lwd=2, col = "green",  xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Counts")
lines(t, line3,lwd=2, col = "black",  xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Counts")
```